# Unable to run Unicorn in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

Trying to run Unicorn as root: `sudo /usr/local/bin/unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb` but getting `rack not available, functionality reduced -- rack and Rack::Builder must be available for processing config.ru`.

If I do `sudo bundle exec /usr/local/bin/unicorn [...]` I get no response.

Unicorn is both in my Gemfile and I've `sudo gem install unicorn`.

I'm using Ruby 2.2.4p230. Is this a version incompatibility?

**config/unicorn.rb**

```
user "myapp", "wheel"

working_directory "/home/www/myapp"
pid "/home/www/myapp/tmp/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/www/myapp/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/www/myapp/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/home/www/myapp/tmp/unicorn.socket", :backlog => 64
listen 5000, :tcp_nopush => true

worker_processes 4
timeout 30
```

Comment: Do you use RVM?  If so, installing unicorn with sudo may cause this weirdness.

Comment: Nope, just pure OS package Ruby.